# why gradle configuring projects every time

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, gradlew

I am try to run libgdx project created by the setup. And as [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline)  when I run command `./gradlew desktop:dist` or `gradle`. Tt try to configure and resolve dependency every time.

```
nets$ ./gradlew desktop:dist
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:classes UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:dist UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 16.29 secs
```

Is there something wrong with configuration or It is the default behavior of gradle.
`16 sec is really long for me`

**EDIT:**
I got this line every time I run task. And it is most time consuming
`Configuring > 0/5 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':classpath`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "try to configure and resolve dependency every time"? Up-to-date checks can take some time, especially when large archives are involved. Reducing the configuration time is something we are working on. In the meantime, make sure not to do anything time-consuming in the configuration phase. All time-consuming work should be done by tasks. Perhaps also ask the libgdx community.

Comment: `:classpath` holds the dependencies of the build itself (not the dependencies of your code). I don't know `libgdx` well enough to tell if this could be made faster.

Comment: should I provide build.xml used by Libgdx. I just start using gradle from command line so I don't know how to configure it. and what is good and bad for speed.

Comment: I i disconnect internet connection it reduced to 7-9 sec. Is there a way to disable dependency resolution every time.

Comment: It build with this error `error listing versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle using class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1. Will attempt an alternate way to list versions. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0`

Comment: It should only resolve every time if configured to do so (default is to cache for 24 hours). Anyway, you can force offline mode with `--offline`. Also, using fixed versions (e.g. `"18.0.2"` rather than `"18.0.+"`) will likely speed up resolution.

Comment: Ok after using `--offline --daemon` it is reduces to 6-7 sec. thanks.